# Virtual method not being overridden?

Tags: c++

Why does the Mammal `speak` method get called instead?

```
int main() {
    Mammal mammal = Cat("CatName", Blue, 9);
    mammal.speak();
}

class Mammal : public Animal{
public:
    virtual void speak() const {
        cout << "Mammal speaks" << endl;
    }
};

class Cat : public Mammal {
public:
    void speak() const {
        cout << "Cat meow!" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: shouldn't it be, `Mammal *mammal = new Cat();`

Comment: Disabling the copy constructor and assignment operator of polymorphic classes can help prevent these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism only works with pointers or references: You declare `mammal` to actually **be** an instance of class `Mammal`.

Changing that to a pointer or a reference changes the semantics in that the pointer or reference refers to something that *is a* `Mammal`.

```
Mammal const & mammal = Cat();
// or
Mammal * mammal = new Cat();
// don't forget the delete, better:
std::unique_ptr<Mammal> mammal = std::make_unique<Cat>();
```

In this context you'll probably also quickly come to know [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/1116364).

Answer (score 1):

This is the case, most Java and C# programmers face with c++. You need to dynamically create an object along with a virtual keyword.

So, the correct way to create an object should be

```
int main
{
  Mammal *mammal = new Cat("CatName", Blue, 9);
  mammal->speak();
}
```